# Using udev rules to let everyone set ip address to a network interface

Tags: permissions, udev, network-interface

I want to let everyone on the system to be able to change the ip address of a network interface. I have wrote a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d` like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}="00:0c:26:c6:70:93", NAME="nic", MODE="0666"
```

The rule matches and my interface is named `nic` in `ifconfig` output. the problem is that, when i log in with a regular user, he still couldn't change the ip address of this interface by using `ifconfig`. Trying this by regular user returns this error message:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network interfaces usually do not appear in `/dev` at all. Their configuration is not done with accesses to device files but with accesses to the NETLINK socket. I don't think that you can give access to this socket to an ordinary user.

You need a suitable sudo rule (and maybe a wrapper script) so that the user can call `ip addr`.

Comment: Sry, i make a mistake by saying that the device file is created in dev directory. I meant that it appears in ifconfig output. Thank you for your answer.